# HowTo list HotList in Midnight Commander (MC) 4.08.24

Tags: midnight-commander

This adds my current directory to hotlist:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> > <kbd>h</kbd>

But I'm not able to list the hotlist. Read https://linux.die.net/man/1/mc:

```
C-\ (control-backslash)
    show the directory hotlist and change to the selected directory.
```

I tried it, but it does nothing here:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>BackSlash</kbd>

I use Kubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your profile,I assume you are using german keyboard layout.
I am also using non-english layout, had similar problem.
I think you should use Ctrl-AltGr-\ .

In any case, you can use the menu system using F-key and cursor navigation:
F9 -> Command -> Directory hotlist